# How To Add Custom Options for dropdown in phtml Magento?

Tags: magento2

```
 <select name="courses" id="coursese" title="name"  class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}">
  <option value="php">html</option>
  <option value="html">php</option>
  </select>
```

instead of a static option. How to give dynamic value as an option by calling PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

**.phtml file :-**

```
<?php $customOption = $block->toOptionArray(); ?>
<select id="custom_option" name="custom_option" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Custom Options')) ?>" class="select"
                    required>
       <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please Select')) ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($customOption as $option) { ?>
                    <?php if (!empty($option['value'])) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($option['label'])) ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**block file :-**

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $this->_options = [];
    $this->_options = [
        ['label' => __('Option 1'), 'value'=>'option_1'],
        ['label' => __('Option 2'), 'value'=>'option_2']
    ];

    return $this->_options;
}
```

> if you want to add a dynamic option then you need to add **foreach**
> in **toOptionArray()** function